# Setting a range on a different sheet without having to select that sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm simply trying to set a Range object to gather data scattered across different columns on one sheet ("Backtest") into one compact set of data (each column one next to another) on a second sheet ("chartData"), so as to easily display those on a chart at later stage.

My understanding is that using the `With... End With` should allow to specify in which sheet the range is to be retrieved by the Set statement. Yet if that sheet is not selected beforehand (as shown on the third line), i run into an

> error 1004 "Application-defined or object-defined error"

.

```
Sub prepareData()

    Set wsChartData = Worksheets.Add
    wsChartData.Name = "chartData"

    wsBacktest.Select

    With wsBacktest
        Set myRangeTimestamp = .Range(Cells(17, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1))
        Set myRangeData = .Range(Cells(17, [colMtM]), Cells(lastRow, [colPnL]))
    End With

    wsChartData.Range("A1").Value = "Timestamp"
    wsChartData.Range("B1").Value = "MtM"
    wsChartData.Range("C1").Value = "PnL"
    myRangeTimestamp.Copy Destination:=wsChartData.Range("A2")
    myRangeData.Copy Destination:=wsChartData.Range("B2")

    wsChartData.Range("A2").EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```

This is not a blocking point as such, but, well, you know... aesthetics...

Comment: One thing I notice, not certain it's the issue, is you should qualify the `Cells` parts as well, e.g.: `Set myRangeTimestamp = .Range(.Cells(17, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 1))` by putting periods before the word `Cells`.

Comment: @DougGlancy it's *precisely* what the issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

> ```
> With wsBacktest
>     Set myRangeTimestamp = .Range(Cells(17, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1))
>     Set myRangeData = .Range(Cells(17, [colMtM]), Cells(lastRow, [colPnL]))
> End With
> ```

Is simply equivalent to this:

```
Set myRangeTimestamp = wsBacktest.Range(Cells(17, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1))
Set myRangeData = wsBacktest.Range(Cells(17, [colMtM]), Cells(lastRow, [colPnL]))
```

Now, `Cells` is implicitly referring to *the active sheet*, [as @Doug mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30387819/excel-vba-setting-a-range-on-a-different-sheet-without-having-to-select-that-s#comment48864725_30387819), so you should also explicitly qualify them:

```
Set myRangeTimestamp = wsBacktest.Range(wsBacktest.Cells(17, 1), wsBacktest.Cells(lastRow, 1))
Set myRangeData = wsBacktest.Range(wsBacktest.Cells(17, [colMtM]), wsBacktest.Cells(lastRow, [colPnL]))
```

The `With` block simply makes fewer repetitions of `wsBacktest`; with or without it, an unqualified `Cells` is an implicit reference to the active sheet, *which you should avoid at least as much as `Select`*.

So the error is occurring because you intend to get a range on the `wsBacktest` sheet, but unless you first activate that sheet, you're using cells from another sheet to get that. Boom.

Answer (score 0):

wsBacktest is neither declared, defined nor set. Excel does not know what you're talking about. Declare it and it will work. See this example.

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
With ws
    Set rng1 = .Range("A1")
    Set rng2 = .Range("B1")
End With
MsgBox rng1 & " " & rng2

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: It's possible that OP has a `CodeName` for the worksheet in question, which would make the identifier available in code without needing to declare or assign it. If the sheet object wasn't declared nor assigned, I believe OP would be facing a runtime error 91, not 1004...

Comment: Thank you teylyn, as hinted by Mat's Mug, all objects are declared in the Declarations part of my module (with Option Explicit a must).I only provided the procedure relevant to my question.